# Ajax request : application/x-www-form-urlencoded params

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

While adding the parameters to get/post request they need to be encoded in application/x-www-form-urlencoded form. So do we need to encode values each time ? Does JavaScript have any method for that ? What are the possible caches ?

On server side when we read the values we do not decode them we directly say Request.Params["key"] and that returns value. Does that mean that they are automatically taken care when we read the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use encodeURIComponent(string);
And yes, the values are already decoded for you.
Check out this article:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=d5756ece-8c33-4edd-80a7-f403e5fd6a07

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) on your values. And yes, the server usually decodes the variables, but you can easily test that.